# iOS app crashing with the following error:Cannot form weak reference to instance of class UICompatibilityInputViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

my iOS app in objective c is crashing due to the following error in Xcode 8 and Xcode 9.

error:

> Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x198bfc00) of class
>   UICompatibilityInputViewController. It is possible that this object
>   was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.

I am not getting any idea about this crash, pls do help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the line of code at which this error occurs

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @3stud1ant3 please wait...will let u know the line in a while.

Comment: it crashes on the line textfield becomeFirstResponder

Comment: Please note: for those text fields i have added inputAccessoryView(for Done button). Is that an issue?

Comment: @ABHILASH P, how  you create accessoryView?.  I am guessing the property of  accessory view is in local.  so it does get deallocated.

Comment: @Yongjoon I create a local instance of UIToolBar in a method and then assign that to a global textfield as textfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;   I commented this usage and my crash got solved. But still not getting the exact reason. May be you are right. I still have confusion regarding this issue.

Comment: @ABHILASHP hey, if it still relevant to you check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227163/5424020 I hope it will help somehow. Maybe you will find other pod or third part lib that the reason.

Comment: @DenisVert Thanks for the information.