# IOS APP CRASH with message _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal

Tags: ios, cordova, crash, cordova-plugins, capacitor

Our ios app suffers some crashes recently with below title ,

```
_objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*)
abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001e6013a00
```

we using capacitor,cordova,ionic for this app

one thing i noticed on resuming the app also this crash event happens, actually firebase log is not adequate to figure out this issue because it has nearly 200 logs with different screens like

```
firebase_screen: splash screen
firebase_screen_class: CAPBridgeViewController
```

this error is mainly in our latest version and ios16 platform

```
# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Application: com.shopperApp
# Platform: apple
# Version: 0.0.8 (0.0.8)
# Issue: 09f591d6fb0a00eb74e378b77e5bf7b3

# Date: Sun Feb 12 2023 00:44:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xea00 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fb4c abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x2fae8 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 26
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2ac64 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 112
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2abf4 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 26
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x61d0 weak_register_no_lock + 332
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0xa6b0 objc_storeWeak + 344
7  UIKitCore                      0x113440 _UIResponderForwarderWantsForwardingFromResponder + 728
8  UIKitCore                      0x32fdc __forwardTouchMethod_block_invoke + 40
9  CoreFoundation                 0xa2c0 __NSSET_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
10 CoreFoundation                 0x856e4 -[__NSSetM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 196
11 UIKitCore                      0x1eb140 forwardTouchMethod + 216
12 UIKitCore                      0xf21f8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 496
13 UIKitCore                      0xf16f0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3224
14 UIKitCore                      0xf09ec -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 740
15 UIKitCore                      0xeec58 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2052
16 UIKitCore                      0x13496c __processEventQueue + 5612
17 UIKitCore                      0x418110 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 220
18 CoreFoundation                 0xcc500 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
19 CoreFoundation                 0xd7e70 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 172
20 CoreFoundation                 0x62224 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 232
21 CoreFoundation                 0x77230 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
22 CoreFoundation                 0x7bdfc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
23 GraphicsServices               0x1984 GSEventRunModal + 160
24 UIKitCore                      0x376e7c -[UIApplication _run] + 868
25 UIKitCore                      0x376af4 UIApplicationMain + 312
26 shopperApp                     0x62e4 main + 7 (AppDelegate.swift:7)
27 ???                            0x1ca24ade0 (Missing)

com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1194 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12a08 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12c44 mach_msg_overwrite + 384
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1688 mach_msg + 20
4  CoreFoundation                 0x76244 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5  CoreFoundation                 0x773f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x7bdfc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
7  Foundation                     0x3e3fc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 208
8  Foundation                     0x3e2f8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 60
9  UIKitCore                      0x49b6d0 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 424
10 Foundation                     0x55f44 __NSThread__start__ + 704
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3060 _pthread_start + 116
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1688 thread_start + 8

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1194 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12a08 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12c44 mach_msg_overwrite + 384
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1688 mach_msg + 20
4  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x188b8 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 194 (FIRCLSMachException.c:194)
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3060 _pthread_start + 116
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1688 thread_start + 8

com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1194 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12a08 mach_msg2_internal + 76
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x12c44 mach_msg_overwrite + 384
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1688 mach_msg + 20
4  CoreFoundation                 0x76244 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
5  CoreFoundation                 0x773f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6  CoreFoundation                 0x7bdfc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
7  CFNetwork                      0x22d6cc _CFURLStorageSessionDisableCache + 51024
8  Foundation                     0x55f44 __NSThread__start__ + 704
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3060 _pthread_start + 116
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1688 thread_start + 8

JavaScriptCore libpas scavenger
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x19e0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x2584 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 1220
2  JavaScriptCore                 0xec4b4 scavenger_thread_main + 1012
3  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3060 _pthread_start + 116
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1688 thread_start + 8

com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1110 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x33e88 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 24
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x344c4 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 128
3  UIKitCore                      0x4999c8 __69+[_UIAsyncInvocationObserver whenInvocationsCompleteForObservers:do:]_block_invoke_2 + 56
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x63850 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x647c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x3bb2c _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 708
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x48d48 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 328
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x49514 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 160
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b14 _pthread_wqthread + 224
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x167c start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1654 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b9c _pthread_wqthread + 360
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x167c start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1654 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b9c _pthread_wqthread + 360
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x167c start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.dnssd.client
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1c34 __ulock_wait + 8
1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x8028 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 168
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x23dc objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 100
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x5a3c objc_destructInstance + 160
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0xe1c8 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
5  libxpc.dylib                   0x26a58 -[OS_xpc_object dealloc] + 52
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x15178 _xpc_dictionary_node_free + 80
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x12cd8 _xpc_dictionary_dispose + 44
8  libxpc.dylib                   0x26a3c -[OS_xpc_object dealloc] + 24
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x80cc _xpc_array_dispose + 40
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x26a3c -[OS_xpc_object dealloc] + 24
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x12d4c _xpc_dictionary_dispose + 160
12 libxpc.dylib                   0x26a3c -[OS_xpc_object dealloc] + 24
13 libxpc.dylib                   0x10040 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 948
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x6487c _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x377c0 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 372
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x3f72c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 308
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x3835c _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 444
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3f72c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 308
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x402e4 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 380
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x4a000 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 612
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b50 _pthread_wqthread + 284
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x167c start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1654 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b9c _pthread_wqthread + 360
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x167c start_wqthread + 8

com.apple.network.connections
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1c34 __ulock_wait + 8
1  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x8028 _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 168
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x23dc objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 100
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x5a3c objc_destructInstance + 160
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0xe1c8 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
5  Network                        0x3611a0 -[OS_nw_array dealloc] + 52
6  Network                        0x12a768 nw_resolver_remove_endpoint_locked + 228
7  Network                        0x12e468 __nw_resolver_create_dns_getaddrinfo_locked_block_invoke.165 + 6932
8  libdns_services.dylib          0x12f0 ___dnssd_getaddrinfo_activate_block_invoke + 204
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x647c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3be7c _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 436
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x4d860 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1552
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x4144c _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1636
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x4a000 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 612
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b50 _pthread_wqthread + 284
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x167c start_wqthread + 8

Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1674 start_wqthread + 270
```

when i googled this error [Crash in UIKitCore [UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] iOS 12 only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52879044/20300178) also shares similar error message but since we are not using native elements i think my cause of problem is from somewhere else?
did any faced this crashes before?
thanks in advance!